# How to compile zlib with clang and cmake

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, zlib, ninja

I tried to build zlib with cmake and clang (8.0) on Windows 64. I did these steps:

```
mkdir build.clang
cd build.clang
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cmake -E env LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld" cmake -H. -G Ninja ^
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" ^
  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID="Clang" ^
  -DCMAKE_AR="c:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\llvm-ar.exe" ^
  -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Generic" ..
```

Configuration run fine (excluding claiming it is not possible to build share libs, but that is not the issue at the moment):

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:186 (add_library):   ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not   support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead   to problems. This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it. 
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: F:/Project-tests/clang_lept/zlib-1.2.11/build.clang
```

However build failed:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
[1/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\crc32.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj   -c ../crc32.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\crc32.obj.d'
[2/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzread.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj   -c ../gzread.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzread.obj.d'
[3/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\compress.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj   -c ../compress.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\compress.obj.d'
[4/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\adler32.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj   -c ../adler32.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\adler32.obj.d'
[5/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzclose.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj   -c ../gzclose.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzclose.obj.d'
[6/36] Building C object CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzlib.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj   -c ../gzlib.c
clang-cl: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-MF' [-Wunknown-argument]
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj'
clang-cl: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzlib.obj.d'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

When I tried to use GCC compatibility of clang - build failed too, but during linking process...

PS: build with VS 2017 (`cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`) works without problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like "less is  more" ;-) . Here are steps to build zlib with ninja, clang and cmake (must be run as admin for installation):

```
set CC=clang-cl
set CFLAGS=-m64 -fmsc-version=1915
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cmake .. -G Ninja  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Program Files\zlib"
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
cmake --build . --config Debug --target install
```

I need to specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, otherwise cmake will install 64bit zlib to "C:/Program Files (x86)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a few more environment variables.

```
set CC=clang-cl
set CXX=clang-cl
set CFLAGS=-m64 -fmsc-version=<your vs version>
set CXXFLAGS=-m64 -fmsc-version=<your vs version>
```

or pass them in your `cmake` call.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but it does not helped... It seems to me there is bug in cmake, because when tried command:
    cl.exe -DNO_FSEEKO -I. -I../  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj -MF CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\gzlib.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj   -c ../gzlib.c

also visual studio complains about it...